# Prove that $a$ or $v$ = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Suppose $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $v \in V$, and av = 0. Prove that $a = 0$ or $v = 0$.

Clearly if $a = 0$, then $av = 0v = 0$.

If $v = 0$, then $av = a0 = 0$.

Is this rigorous enough to be an acceptable proof answer? I feel like I am missing something here.

Comment: You're proving the wrong direction.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You proved if $a=0$ or $v=0$ then $av=0$.  You're asked to prove if $av=0$ then $a=0$ or $v=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach the problem in two cases:

Case 1 ($a\ne 0$): In this case there are less restrictions on $a$. Maybe you can manipulate the equations to get $v=0$.

Case 2 ($a=0$): This case is easy, because it assumes what you want to prove. So you'd be done.

Comment: For Case 1, since $a\neq 0$, you could divide both sides by $a$ and then argue that $v={1 \over a}0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, this is an if and only if statement and you proved the converse. A good proof for the other direction is: if $a=0$ we are good. If $a\neq 0$, $v=a^{-1}(av)=0$.

Comment: The atated problem is not “if and only if.”

Comment: @Randall you think $av=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $v=0$ is wrong?

Comment: No, I know it to be true but that was not OP’s question.

Comment: @Randall clearly it was.

Comment: You are correct. Here is a link to a similar proof: https://imgur.com/a/eWoEV

Answer (score 0):

You can try the contrapositive form, that is, since do you want to prove that
$$\textrm{if } av=0_V \textrm{ then } a=0 \textrm{ or } v=0_V$$
this is the same as prove that
$$\textrm{if } a\neq0 \textrm{ and } v\neq0_V \textrm{ then } av\neq0_V$$
And the latter is clearly true (although it could be argued by saying what would happen otherwise).

Comment: I don’t think the latter is any more obvious than the original statement and is more likely to confound a beginner.

Comment: @Randall What do you suggest then?

Comment: Assume $a \neq 0$.  Then $v=a^{-1}av = a^{-1}0=0$.

Comment: None of this matters, since this is a dupe anyway.